# jQuery if A length == 0 && B length == 1 do something

Tags: jquery, if-statement

How do I get this code to work correctly if I want (A.length == 0 && B.length == 1)?

```
    $(function() {
if (($('.thePrices').find('.addcartforlower').length == 0 ) && ($('.exclusive').length == 1 )) {
    $('.thePrices').find('a').after($('.wb_main').addClass('winbuyerset'));
$('.thePrices').find('.wb_main').before($('#compare'));   

      }
  });
```

Comment: @Todd You're using `jQuery` and `$` interchangeably?

Comment: @Todd And what's with the `[id=...]` and `[class=...]` attribute selectors? You can use dedicated ID (`#`) and class (`.`) selectors for that...

Comment: -1 "Not a real question" -- Proposes a simple condition (one that is arguably implemented), then asks how to "make it work correctly" without explaining what doesn't work, etc. Please take some time formulating a good, interesting SO question.

Comment: Perhaps the HTML that this goes with would help in figuring out why the if's don't work? It's more than likely a misspelling of one of the selectors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

extract

```
$('.thePrices').find('.addcartforlower').length
```

into a variable like so:

```
var addcartforlowerlength = $('.thePrices').find('.addcartforlower').length;
```

do something similar for the other side. Then your test will be simple:

```
if (addcartforlowerlength === 0 && exclusivelength === 1)
```

hope this helps

Comment: Should be === instead of == :)

Comment: good old javascript. updated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
if($('.thePrices').find('.addcartforlower').length == 0 && $('.exclusive').length == 1)
{ .... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there's nothing wrong with your if statement (but you should in that case use === instead of ==), but I see that you are using before and after, what do you mean by that?

after() is used to insert something after the element in the dom, like this:

```
$('#header').after('<div id="main" />');
```

And the same thing for before but before the element. What you probably are looking for are prev() and next(). Or if you want to actually insert content you're almost right, but what you are doing is trying to select an element rather than creating one. Do like this:

```
$('.thePrices').find('a').after('<div class="wb_main.winbuyerset />');
```

But from you information it's impossible to know what you want.

Answer (score -2):

Your actual function declaration syntax is screwed up. The "if" code is correct, although indented poorly:

```
if (($('.thePrices').find('.addcartforlower').length == 0 ) && ($('.exclusive').length == 1 )) {
    $('.thePrices').find('a').after(jQuery('div[class="wb_main"]:eq(0)').addClass('winbuyerset'));
    $('.thePrices').find('.wb_main').before(jQuery('div[id="compare"]:eq(0)'));
}
```

To declare a function, use a form like:

```
var function_name = function() {
    [...]
};
```

To just run something on page-load, use a form like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    [...]
});
```

Comment: His function is fine. That's jquery syntax for the document.ready event listener

Comment: $(function(){}); Is for executing when the dom is done loading. Like $.ready();
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3

Comment: `$` *is* a function-object (`jQuery` is a function-object) and, when passed a function-object (instead of say, a selector or DOM element), is synonymous with `$.ready`

Comment: I gave a minus because the answer is misleading and wrong.